# DetailsView binding to child object

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, detailsview, boundfield

I am trying to bind a BoundField of a DetailsView control to a child object of the datasource, I can't seem to find the right syntax.

Here's some sample code;

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Address.Postcode" HeaderText="PostCode" />
```

This code doesn't work but you get the idea.

Using this code I get the exception;
A field or property with the name 'Address.Postcode' was not found on the selected data source.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you just tried to use Postcode instead of Address.Postcode

Comment: Just tried. Nope doesn't find it.

Comment: Uhmmm try to bind the object to the dataform that contains the datafield as it's CurrentItem then try to bind Postcode to your data field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use item template ....
take a look at [this link](http://www.michaelkbell.com/index.php/2006/09/06/binding-to-an-objectdatasource-where-the-object-has-child-objects/)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=”First Name” SortExpression=”Person.FirstName”>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID=”FirstNameLabel” runat=”server” Text=’<%# Eval(“Person.FirstName”) %>’></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```